# why my struct crash when it contains string?

Tags: c++, string

I met a problem which i think it's very meaningful to know std::string.

I design a queue(lockfree queue) by c, code is:
kfifo.c

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define min(X,Y) ((X) < (Y) ? (X) : (Y))

struct kfifo{
    char* buffer;  // data address pointer
    unsigned int index[96];
};

static unsigned long roundup_pow_of_2(unsigned long n) {  // calculate the nearest pow(2) value of n
// so the % operation can be replaced by bit operation &, which is faster
  unsigned long rval = 1;
  while (rval < n) rval <<= 1;
  return rval;
}

static bool is_power_of_2(unsigned long n) {
  return (n != 0 && ((n & (n - 1)) == 0));
}

static void kfifo_init(struct kfifo* fifo,  char* buffer, unsigned int size, size_t elemSize) {
  // init struct
  assert(is_power_of_2(size));
  memset(fifo->index, 0, sizeof(fifo->index));
  fifo->buffer = buffer;
  fifo->index[51] = elemSize;
  fifo->index[34] = size < 2 ? 0: size;
}

int kfifo_alloc(struct kfifo* fifo, unsigned int size, size_t elemSize) {
  /* 
  * round up to the next power of 2, since our 'let the indices 
  * wrap' tachnique works only in this case. 
  */
  if (!is_power_of_2(size)) {
    size = roundup_pow_of_2(size);
  }

  // allocate memory
  char* buffer = (char*)malloc(size * elemSize);
  if (!buffer)
    return 0;

  // init struct
  kfifo_init(fifo, buffer, size, elemSize);
  return 1;
}

void kfifo_free(struct kfifo *fifo) {  // free resource
  free(fifo->buffer);
  fifo->index[17] = fifo->index[0] = fifo->index[34] = fifo->index[51] = 0;
  // fifo->buffer = NULL;
}

static inline unsigned int kfifo_avail_int(struct kfifo *fifo) {  // left space of fifo
    return fifo->index[34] - (fifo->index[17] - fifo->index[0]);
}

static inline unsigned int kfifo_in_data(struct kfifo *fifo, char *from) {
  unsigned int off_int = (fifo->index[17] & (fifo->index[34] - 1));  // next_in place, int
  unsigned int l = min(1, (fifo->index[34] - off_int));
  memcpy(fifo->buffer + off_int * fifo->index[51], from, l*fifo->index[51]);
  memcpy(fifo->buffer, from + l*fifo->index[51], (1 - l) * fifo->index[51]);
  if (fifo->buffer + off_int*fifo->index[51] == NULL) {  // if execute this in an unexpected order
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

unsigned int kfifo_push(struct kfifo* fifo, char* buffer) {
  int len = min(kfifo_avail_int(fifo), 1);
  if (!kfifo_in_data(fifo, buffer)) {
    return 0;
  }
  fifo->index[17] += len;
  return len;
}

static inline unsigned int kfifo_out_data(struct kfifo *fifo, char *to) {
  unsigned int off = (fifo->index[0] & (fifo->index[34]-1));
  unsigned int l = min(1, (fifo->index[34] - off));
  memcpy(to, fifo->buffer + off * fifo->index[51], l*fifo->index[51]);
  memcpy(to + l*fifo->index[51], fifo->buffer, (1 - l)*fifo->index[51]);
  // char* p = fifo->buffer + off * fifo->index[51];
  // p = NULL;  // reset the out position as NULL
  return 1;
}

unsigned int kfifo_get(struct kfifo* fifo, char* buffer){
  int len = min(fifo->index[17] - fifo->index[0], 1);
  if (!kfifo_out_data(fifo, buffer)) {
    return 0;
  }
  fifo->index[0] += len;
  return len;
}
```

and in order to use it in c++, i have a wrapper:
fifo_queue.h

```
#include "kfifo_ing.c"

template <typename T>
class FIFO_Queue {
 public:
  FIFO_Queue(int size) {
    kfifo_alloc(&k, size, sizeof(T));
  }
  ~FIFO_Queue() {
    // kfifo_free(&k);
  }
  bool push(const T& t) {
    return kfifo_push(&k, (char*)(&t));
  }

  bool pop(T& t) {
    return kfifo_get(&k, (char*)(&t));
  }
 private:
  kfifo k;
};
```

i have tested this queue, i think it is correct when the element is int of simple struct.

but the strange things happen when the struct has std::string object, here is my test code:

```
#include "fifo_queue.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct huang {
  int a;
  string b;  // if dont have b, everything is good, but once add it, crashed!!!!!!!!
  double c;
  void Show(FILE* stream) const {
    fprintf(stream, "%d %lf\n", a, c); 
  }
};

FIFO_Queue<huang>q(80);

int main() {
  huang h;
  h.a = 1;
  q.push(h);
  q.pop(h);
  q.pop(h); // if no this, wont crash!!!!
  return 0;
}
```

the code crashed, when i use gdb to check the stack,it warns me the error happens in ~basic_string(),
I am confused, i know string is a complex design datastructure, which have two pointer.
But can anyone explain this? Is it caused by double free? Is there any methods can make it works?

Comment: Huang, your code is really hard to follow. Can you try to simplify more? You are mixing C and C++. Probably the issue is memory allocation, you are probably double freeing somewhere. Try to use templates in your fifo struct instead of the char pointer cast you are currently doing. Try to simplify your code by using std:: functions and datatypes. I understand that you want to lean how to implement a queue instead of using std::queue, but we need to simplify things. :)

Comment: @TomazCanabrava  Thanks Tomaz, sorry for the mess code, i will make it clear. It's not good to read, i apologize

Comment: The C++ `huang` struct won't `memcpy` because it has a non-trivial C++ member variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    huang h;
    h.a = 1;
    q.push(h);
    q.pop(h);
    q.pop(h); // if no this, wont crash!!!!
    return 0;
}
```

In your code, you pushed only 1 `huang` onto your `q`. But you pop twice. I suspect that what you're putting into `h` in the second pop does not have a properly constructed `string b` in `huang`. When you leave scope for `h`, `string b` gets destructed and likely accessing memory that doesn't belong to your process and crashes as a result.